# In the Ramakien, why did Phra Narai declare that when both him and Nontuk reincarnate they’ll fight each other again?

Tags: hindu

When Phra Narai caught Nontuk off guard and forced him onto the ground (where he proceeded to act like a whiny little bitch to Phra Narai) and made the absolutely absurd statement that he could’ve easily defeated Phra Narai but Phra Narai was being uNFaiR since he had four arms. In that case, why not just tell Nontuk to shut his whiny ass wOe Is mE up, lop his head off, and end it at that? Not saying that I oppose Phra Narai or his action since I think that he’s a badass but it does make me wonder.